# PowerShell trying to list users who have group membership similar string

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a function that helps me grab over 20k users in our AllUsers group (gets ObjectClass,Name,SamAccountname,DistinguishedName). I'm trying to list anyone who has CBA-* groups, but the loop seems to repeat the output a couple of times per user (after the 1st one), when I only want one iteration (many CBA-* possibilities). Here's what I have. Also, I get errors "Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership : The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error." Any ideas why that would happen? I'm not sure I can see why my code repeats maybe twice, but then seems to move on to the next user just fine?

```
ForEach ($User in $Users) {

    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $User.SamAccountName | 
    Select Name | 
    Where-Object {$_.Name -like 'CBA-*'} | 
    ForEach-Object { $User_MemberOf += @($_.Name) } 


  ForEach ($Group in $User_MemberOf) {
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            SID = $User.SamAccountName
            Name = $User.name
            Group = $Group 
        }  | Export-Csv -Path $logs -NoTypeInformation -Append       
        }
        }
```

Comment: So, you just want a yes/no answer to whether the user is a member of any group with a name that starts with `CBA-`? Not all the individual group names

Comment: No, I'm just trying to list each CBA group that a user is in (by name). I think the problem is with the += @($_.Name). I probably don't need that as it appears to be storing the previous user's CBA groups then adding those to the next user...

Comment: Yes, add `$User_MemberOf = @()` just after `foreach($User in $Users){` to "reset" it for each iteration

Comment: Ah, so much better! Thanks once again Mathias! Let me mark your answer.

Comment: Added a proper answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each loop iteration, you continue to assign values to `$User_MemberOf` with the addition operator (`+=`) meaning that for each new user it gets "sanded" more and more with the previous users' memberships.

Two ways to avoid:

#### Initialize `$User_MemberOf` as an empty array at the start of each loop iteration:

```
foreach($User in $Users){
    $User_MemberOf = @()

    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $User.SamAccountName |Select -Expand Name |Where-Object {
      $_ -like 'CBA-*'
    } |ForEach-Object { 
      $User_MemberOf += $_ 
    }

    foreach($Group in $User_MemberOf){
        # export to CSV
    }
}
```

#### Assign output directly from pipeline:

```
foreach($User in $Users){
    $User_MemberOf = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $User.SamAccountName |Select -Expand Name |Where-Object {
      $_ -like 'CBA-*'
    } |ForEach-Object { 
      $User_MemberOf += $_ 
    }

    foreach($Group in $User_MemberOf){
        # export to CSV
    }
}
```